# MVVM ICommand Binding "higher up"

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, uwp, icommand

I'm working on a shopping-cart like application as a way to practice the MVVM design pattern.

I have a View whose ViewModel is pretty much just a **ShoppingCart**, and the **ShoppingCart** is primarily a list of **Product**s.

Right now, my view shows the **Products** in a **GridView**, which uses a DataTemplate to show the *Name* , *Price*, and a Remove button for each **Product**. The thing is, due to databinding, if I try databinding the *Command* attribute of the Remove button to a **RemoveCommand** property in my ViewModel, the code fails because it looks for **RemoveCommand** in the **Product** class instead of the **ViewModel** class.

I highly doubt I want to break encapsulation and have the **Product** deal with removing itself from a **ShoppingCart**, but I can't seem to figure out the right way to tackle this issue.

Comment: We need to see your ViewModel, View and Product classes.

Comment: While that's a great idea if I'm hitting a syntax roadblock, I'm really looking for a general, concept-based solution rather than have someone spit out the code for me to copy. That's why I purposefully refrained from posting the XAML/C# for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your GridView a name and do a `Command="{Binding ElementName=theGridView, Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand}"`. You can also use a RelativeSource binding, although I think the former is faster.

You'll also want to pass the Product itself into the command handler so you know which one the user has clicked on, do that with `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"`. The RemoveCommand property should be declared to return type ICommand but should return a generic instance of RelayCommand i.e.:

```
public ICommand RemoveCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<Product>(OnRemove); } }
private void OnRemove(Product product)
{
    // remove it here
}
```

Comment: Yep! It sounds like I have to tinker with my ICommand implementation, since right now I'm using the Action type, which doesn't allow for CommandParameters.
But I think it's much slicker if I do use CommandParameter, since then I don't have to bind to a CurrentlySelectedProduct in the ViewModel.

Comment: @afding this is the better solution.  Except the "Path=." is redundant.  {Binding} is sufficient.  Using `ElementName` is better than using a RelativeSource binding.

Answer (score 1):

use RelativeSource(ancestor) binding as a generic solution.

```
   Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GridView}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand}"
```

So i hope the class which gridview has as a datacontext is holding this RemoveCommand command. Or else in AncestorType put the control that has such datacontext which holds RemoveCommand command.

This was you can keep your encapsulation and binding will work too.

Comment: RemoveCommand is defined in viewmodel (GridView's DataContext) not in GridView itself. You probably meant 'Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand'